# How to remove the text between the tags in c#?

Tags: c#

Following HTML statements are stored in a string.
I need to remove the  text written between the HTML tags  `<style>`and  `</style>`

```
<html> <head><style type="text/css">
        @font-face { 
            font-family: "tunga";
            src: url(tunga.TTF); 
        }

        body {              
            font-family:"tunga";
            padding:0;
            margin: 0;
        }


        table {
            font-family:"tunga";
            padding:0;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none
        }

    </style></head>  <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="10" topmargin="0" >
    </body>
    </html>
```

How to solve this problem  using  c# code?

Comment: @gap.dev Did you try my code

Comment: @gap.dev pls mark it as ans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string str = "<html> <head><style type='text/css'> jhiun  </style></head> </html>";
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            string strToRemove = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("<style"), str.IndexOf("</style>") - str.IndexOf("<style") + 8); 
            Console.WriteLine(str.Replace(strToRemove,""));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 9):

Use HtmlAgilityPack to load the Html file.

Open the file:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(myHtmlString);
```

Then remove the nodes:

```
foreach(var descendant in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToList())
    descendant.Remove()
```

Then get the string the represent the HTML file:

```
string htmlWithoutStyle = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: There's no need to import an extra library just for this.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko So you'd rather write lengthy string comparison boiler plate code?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Html parsing is not as simple as you may think.

Comment: Why is parsing needed? You find the start and end and remove any text inbetween.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Parsing html is quite a tricky business. Sure you could come up with a specific "parser" to solve this problem, but why not just use an existing library to solve the problem in minimal time? Hand parsing html (with regex, perhaps) is evil.

Comment: search <style> and </style> and delete the text between.. there is really no parsing needed for that

Comment: @splender, why load an un-needed library into memory when you don't need it. The OP has specific requirements which can be met without this.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: whilst it is easy to come up with a solution that works for the vast majority of cases, these crude solutions that search for tags or parts of tags could easily break down. What is your aversion, exactly, for using an additional dynamically linked library?

Comment: @PaulRuane Libraries and tools are apparently not needed for programming. We should all write our programs in binary machine code because we're hardcore.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko what happen if you have more than one couple of style tag in a page? The replace solution will fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
_htmlContent = Regex.Replace(_htmlContent, "< style.*?< /style>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Try this. And please remove the extraspace after the less than `<` sign if you are feeling lazy and wanna copy paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This tool is designed for html parsing etc. Writing a regex or parsing it your self will only bring you in trouble and can lead to securtyrisks in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Use HtmlAgilityPack. Don't try to roll your own parser.

```
var doc=new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//style").RemoveAllChildren();
using(var sw=new StringWriter())
{
    doc.Save(sw);
    var moddedHtml=sw.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use extra libraries here. Try something like this.

```
// Find the start tag
var start = html.IndexOf("<style");

// Find the end tag
var end = html.IndexOf("</style>") + 8;

// Remove the tag using Substring
var newHtml = html.Substring(0, start - 1) + html.Substring(end);
```

Comment: -1. `</style  >` is a legal closing tag. How are you going to handle that? Use a proper parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the extra library or just a simple string remove...

```
RemoveHTMLTagsText("your html statement", "<style>");

public static string RemoveHTMLTagsText(string html, string tag)
{
      int startIndex = html.IndexOf(tag.Remove(tag.Length - 1));
      startIndex = html.IndexOf(">", startIndex) + 1;
      int endIndex = html.IndexOf(tag.Insert(1, "/"), startIndex) - startIndex;
      html = html.Remove(startIndex, endIndex);
      return html;
}
```